# insert into array of custom type in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have created a custom Postgres type with :

```
CREATE TYPE new_type AS (new_date timestamp, some_int bigint);
```

i have a table that store arrays of new_type like:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (
    table_id uuid primary key,
    new_type_list new_type[] not null
)
```

and i insert data in this table with something like this:

```
INSERT INTO new_table VALUES (
    '*inApplicationGeneratedRandomUUID*',
    ARRAY[[NOW()::timestamp, '146252'::bigint],
          [NOW()::timestamp, '526685'::bigint]]::new_type[]
)
```

and i get this error

```
ERROR: cannot cast type timestamp without time zone to new_type
```

What am I missing?
I've also tried array syntax that uses {} but nothing better.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be:

```
INSERT INTO new_table VALUES (
    '9fd92c53-d0d8-4aba-8925-1bd648d565f2'::uuid,
    ARRAY[ row(now(), 146252)::new_type,
           row(now(), 526685)::new_type
     ] );
```

Note that you have to *cast* the `row` type to `::new_type`.

As an alternative, you could also write:

```
INSERT INTO new_table VALUES (
    '9fd92c53-d0d8-4aba-7925-1ad648d565f2'::uuid,
    ARRAY['("now", 146252)'::new_type,
          '("now", 526685)'::new_type
     ] );
```

Check PostgreSQL documentation about [Composite Value Input](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html#AEN8046).